# How to instruct TypeScript tsc to disregard @ts-ignore and @ts-nocheck directives?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I am looking for a `tsconfig.json` setting and/or `tsc` command-line option to make TypeScript disregard all `@ts-ignore` and `@ts-nocheck` annotations in code; meaning, it should check code as normal, and not ignore errors normally suppressed by these directives.

*Why*: So that `tsc` can be run as a Continuous Integration check and will not allow this "lazy" use of bypassing TypeScript by just adding `@ts-ignore` instead of properly fixing the root cause of type errors.

Comment: This in no way invalidates your question, but...can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: I too see no point in doing this, since `ts-ignore` and `ts-nocheck` do exactly what they're supposed to do. I'm not aware of a solution for this question other than "searching and replacing"

Comment: @RyanM Added the "Why" section to the question. 
@MikeS. Hmm, perhaps I could just implement a `grep` for `@ts-ignore` etc. which would fail if it finds it anywhere